# Find first match in html table and output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have the following problem;

An example of my table is below;

```
<table id="clientDetails">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Client - Mr Smith</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Client - Mr Ted</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Client - Mr Dhillon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Client - Mr Sean</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Client - Mr Hart</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

and the Jquery that I am trying to get working is;

```
$(function test() {
    var elTableRow = document.getElementById("clientDetails");
    var elTableCells = elTableRow.getElementsByTagName("td");
    var test = alert(elTableCells[1].innerText);
    $('body').append(test);
    }
)
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: Why you are mixing jQuery with native JavaScript Document methods ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(body).append($($('#clientDetails').find("td:contains('Client -')")[2]).html());
```

This will append the content of the third "Client" row to the body. Assuming of course that there is a third row...

Comment: Do you know how I would go about outputting this in a specific area of my body section, for example within a div or table object?

Comment: Take a look at the [selectors section of the jQuery API](http://overapi.com/jquery/). You can also use [the DOM document model methods](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-getElBId) and set the [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function test() {
    $('body').append($('#clientDetails tbody td:first-child').html());

     // or
     // $('#clientDetails tbody tr:first td').text();

     // to select the third client:
     // $('#clientDetails tbody tr:eq(2) td').text();
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
  $('body').append($('#clientDetails').find('td').first().html());
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/juanchopx2/FW9CF/)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Juanchox2 it helped a lot.

Comment: Could you vote for my solution if it worked for you? :P Thanks!

Comment: sorry I can only vote for one and the answer that Edgar Allan Pwn gave also finds the nth Clients.